# Vue.set reactivity not working inside child component

Tags: vue.js

```
//1. working
changeColorType: function(e){
    this.$parent.activeIcon.type = e.target.value;
    this.$parent.$forceUpdate();
}   

//2. working
changeColorType: function(e){
    this.$parent.activeIcon = $.extend({}, this.$parent.activeIcon, {type: e.target.value})
}   

//3. not working
changeColorType: function(e){
    this.$parent.activeIcon.type = e.target.value;
}    

//4. not working
changeColorType: function(e){
    Vue.set(this.$parent.activeIcon, 'type', e.target.value);
}    

//5. not working
changeColorType: function(e){
    this.$parent.$set(this.$parent.activeIcon, 'type', e.target.value);
}
```

I understand why 1. and 2. working, 3. not working;
But I thought 4. and 5. should work too!

Q:
Why 4. and 5. not working?

Comment: You know that this direct way to set parent component data is a super bad practice, right? :)

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Hi Vovchisko, Thanks for reply. You are right, it is not very good. But I really curious why 3. and 4. not working.

Comment: Try to `console.log(this.$parent, this.$parent.activeIcon)` to look up what is inside.

Comment: this.$parent.activeIcon = $.extend({}, this.$parent.activeIcon, {type: e.target.value});
this code works. But I wish 3. and 4. work.